# How can I show notify-send messages triggered by crontab?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, cron, notify-send

test.sh: `/usr/bin/notify-send "test"`

The following works: `bash ~/Documents/test.sh`

BUT the crontab never shows the notification. Why?

`*/1 * * * * bash ~/Documents/test.sh`

Comment: We should export some environment variables. What is your Ubuntu version and Desktop Environment?

Comment: @dessert, maybe [`$DISPLAY`](https://askubuntu.com/a/744751/566421) could be enough, but it will fail with the `@reboot` jobs. Recently I've found this complete solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/970795/566421

Comment: if I set DISPLAY to 99, notify-send still works in 17.10 with wayland. so $DISPLAY ist not the problem. I tested "sudo -u myuser notify-send test" and this does not work also.

Comment: This is perhaps not only a cron problem, I can't make `notify-send` work from the console or over ssh.

Comment: @pa4080 `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To execute any GUI related app from Cron you should export few desktop environment variables. The below solution is [based on this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/970795/566421) where are provided more details.

#### How to launch any GUI related application from `crontab` in Ubuntu 16.04, 17.10, 18.04 and other Ubuntu distributions with Gnome

Create a startup script that will export the desktop environment variables and will launch your application. Let's call it `gui-launcher`. Its content should be (*referencs: [[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978711/how-do-i-split-a-proc-environ-file-in-separate-lines), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909045/6543935) and [[3]](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6672/xargs-for-builtin-bash-commands)*):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -e

# NAME: gui-launcher

# Check whether the user is logged-in
while [ -z "$(pgrep gnome-session -n -U $UID)" ]; do sleep 3; done

# Export the current desktop session environment variables
# Sometimes it try to change $UID so we must remove -e option or use 2>/dev/null
export $(xargs -0 -a "/proc/$(pgrep gnome-session -n -U $UID)/environ") 2>/dev/null 

# Execute the input command
nohup "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 &

exit 0
```

- For other Desktop Environments change `gnome-session` in this part `$(pgrep gnome-session -n -U $UID)` with the name of the process of the DE in use, for example `mate-session`. A list of the most Ubuntu DE is [presented here](https://github.com/metalevel-tech/cron-gui-launcher#supportedtested-desktop-environments). Lubuntu implementation of the same script - [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1019449/566421). The script could be used to launch GUI app from TTY or SSH session in the current user's Desktop session.
- Make the file executable: `chmod +x gui-launcher`.
- The script will work until the user is logged-in, including a locked screen.
- **Please don't modify and run the script as root. It could be harmful for the system!**

Then use it within `crontab` in this way:

```
*/1 * * * * /full/path/to/gui-launcher "/full/path/to/the-target-application"
```

Here is how it works on Ubuntu 17.10 on Wayland:

[image]

---

- Here is presented an implementation of the same script over SSH: [How to run script (.sh) files in a new terminal after connecting to Ubuntu 16.04 server via ssh?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040852/566421)
- Here are presented more explanations: [Cron job to run python script at reboot does not work](https://askubuntu.com/q/970771/566421).
- And one more example: [Adjust brightness with xrandr and cron job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958228/adjust-brightness-with-xrandr-and-cron-job)

Comment: While this may technically "work" and "solve" the primary thing asked about, it would probably be best to advise that you shouldn't do such things from cron, and if it's something that a user needs to see a notification for, should be something running under the user's session only when logged in, as running this via cron would be wasteful when logged out an the machine is on.

Comment: @dobey, the above script will work only when the user is logged-in. But what is the actual problem when we launch GUI applications from Cron?

Comment: whether it is the optimal solution or not, it works!

Comment: @pa4080 Well, "notify-send" is not a GUI application, for one, so I'm not sure what bearing that has on it. However, randomly launching GUI applications from the background, is bad design.  I don't know what the specific goal is in the specific instance of this question, but there's almost certainly a better and more efficient way to achieve it, than via cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Environment for cron and your regular user can be different.

When you're using any scripts in cron better to put full path to them.

Comment: Using absolute path does not show the notification either

Comment: The first sentence is the actual issue. The second sentence is not a problem. DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is not set in the cron environment, and so notify-send can't talk to the notification service, and dbus will try to start a new session bus and fail.

Comment: @dobey is right. Exporting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS solved my problem.