# How do I split a "/proc/*/environ" file in separate lines?

Tags: command-line, bash, proc

I'm trying to get the content of any `/proc/*PID*/environ` file in more readable format. I'm able to do that in the way shown below, but I'm sure this isn't the proper way.

```bsh
$ cat "/proc/$(pgrep gnome-session -n -U $UID)/environ"
USER=spasTEXTDOMAIN=im-configXDG_SEAT=seat0XDG_SESSION_TYPE=waylandSHLVL=1QT4_IM_MODULE=ximHOME=/home/spasDESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntuGNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntuDBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/busIM_CONFIG_PHASE=2LOGNAME=spasGTK_IM_MODULE=ibusJOURNAL_STREAM=9:147845_=/usr/bin/gnome-sessionUSERNAME=spasXDG_SESSION_ID=70PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/binXDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000LANG=en_US.UTF-8XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOMEXDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntuXMODIFIERS=@im=ibusSHELL=/bin/bashGDMSESSION=ubuntuTEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/XDG_VTNR=2QT_IM_MODULE=ximPWD=/home/spasCLUTTER_IM_MODULE=ximXDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktopXDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
```

```bsh
$ cat -e "/proc/$(pgrep gnome-session -n -U $UID)/environ"
USER=spas^@TEXTDOMAIN=im-config^@XDG_SEAT=seat0^@XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland^@SHLVL=1^@QT4_IM_MODULE=xim^@HOME=/home/spas^@DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu^@GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu^@DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus^@IM_CONFIG_PHASE=2^@LOGNAME=spas^@GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus^@JOURNAL_STREAM=9:147845^@_=/usr/bin/gnome-session^@USERNAME=spas^@XDG_SESSION_ID=70^@PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin^@XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000^@LANG=en_US.UTF-8^@XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME^@XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu^@XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus^@SHELL=/bin/bash^@GDMSESSION=ubuntu^@TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/^@XDG_VTNR=2^@QT_IM_MODULE=xim^@PWD=/home/spas^@CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim^@XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop^@XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg^@
```

```bsh
$ cat -e "/proc/$(pgrep gnome-session -n -U $UID)/environ" | sed 's/\^@/\n/g'
USER=spas
TEXTDOMAIN=im-config
XDG_SEAT=seat0
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland
...
```

Maybe I must assign a specific value to `$IFS`, but what is it? What is the proper way to achieve the above result?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The entries are separated by the null character, see [`man 5 proc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/proc.5.html):

```
/proc/[pid]/environ
      This file contains the environment for the process.  The entries
      are separated by null bytes ('\0'), and there may be a null byte
      at  the  end.
```

So a simple way is to apply `xargs -0 -L1` on it:

```
$ xargs -0 -L1 -a /proc/self/environ
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
USER=muru
LOGNAME=muru
HOME=/home/muru
MAIL=/var/mail/muru
SHELL=/bin/zsh
...
```

- `-0` - read null-delimited lines,
- `-L1` - read one line per execution of command
- `-a file` read lines from `file`
- and if no command is specified, `xargs` simply prints the line.

Various GNU commands have options to work with null-delimited data: `-z` for `sed`, `sort`, `uniq`, `grep` etc, and for filenames, `-print0` with `find` and `-Z` with grep.

Alternatively, you can use plain old bash:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r line
do
    printf "%q\n" "$line"
done < /proc/.../environ
```

`-d ''` tells `read` to read until a null byte, `IFS=` and `-r` prevent field-splitting and backslash-escaping, so that the data is read as-is, `%q` will quote special characters in output.

Since you did use `sed`, you could have done:

```
sed -z 's/$/\n/' /proc/.../environ
```

which just tacks on a newline at the end of each null-delimited line.

Comment: +1 for the default of `xargs` to print, I wasn't aware of that

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that the entries are null-terminated precisely *because* it is the only character that cannot be part of a value. If you replace them with newlines, you potentially introduce an ambiguity of whether two consecutive lines represent two variables, or one variable whose value contains a newline followed by what looks like an assignment.

Comment: +1 The plain old bash answer is useful for containers where you don't have a lot else.

Answer (score 23):

- You could use `cut`:

  ```
  cut -d '' -f1- --output-delimiter=$'\n' /proc/$pid/environ
  ```

  using null as a delimiter, and outputting a newline delimiter, optionally picking only certain fields/lines.
- Or filter through `tr`, translating nulls to newlines:

  ```
  tr '\0' '\n' </proc/$pid/environ
  ```
- Or just stick with your `sed` version...

Comment: I've been using `tr '\0' '\n'` ever since I can recall. That's the most intuitive way for me to express "replace all NULs with newlines", and hence my personal preferred solution.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `strings` as follows:

```
strings /proc/$(pgrep gnome-session -n -U $UID)/environ
```

Sample of the output:

```
$ strings /proc/$(pgrep gnome-session -n -U $UID)/environ
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=
LANGUAGE=en_US
J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
XDG_SEAT=seat0
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu
SESSION=ubuntu
```

[man strings](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/arm-none-eabi-strings.1.html)

> NAME
>
> ```
>    strings - print the strings of printable characters in files.
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    For each file given, GNU strings prints the printable character
>    sequences that are at least 4 characters long (or the number given with
>    the options below) and are followed by an unprintable character.  By
>    default, it only prints the strings from the initialized and loaded
>    sections of object files; for other types of files, it prints the
>    strings from the whole file.
>
>    strings is mainly useful for determining the contents of non-text
>    files.
> ```

Comment: that's beautiful.

Comment: As written in the quoted manual, `strings` only prints strings of length >= 4. Environment variables like `A=1` will be ignored. Also, whitespace (expect space and tab) is ignored. You can change this by using `strings -n2 -w` instead.

Comment: perfect, love it. also thanks for the -n2 thingy

Answer (score 4):

"man proc", search "environ", help text says:

> Thus, to print out the envi‐ronment of process 1, you would do:
>
> ```
> $ strings /proc/1/environ
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Building on @muru's answer, you can then export those variables with the following:

```
`cat /proc/1/environ | xargs -0 -L1 -I{} echo export {}`
```

Comment: Actually I'm using the command: `export $(xargs -0 -a "/proc/$(pgrep gnome-session -n -U $UID)/environ")`, reference: [How can I show notify-send messages triggered by crontab?](https://askubuntu.com/a/978413/566421)

Comment: @pa4080 Ah nice

Answer (score -4):

```
hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X "' /proc/PID/environ |sed -e 's/00/0a/g' | xxd -r -p
```

how does this work
first `hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X "' /proc/PID/environ` will (if you replace PID with the pid of the program or self) print all of the file in hex with bite separated with a space. next i pipe it into `sed -e 's/00/0a/g'` which takes all 00 aka nulls which are used as separators for each entry and converts them into newlines. lest i use `xxd -r -p` to convert back the hex to binary aka readable text.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how this works and how this will solve OP's question?

Comment: A good explaination would be really interesting. I understand that hexdump is used to make a hexadecimal representation of the environ-content which used to convert NUL-Characters into newlines and convert it back into binary. I'm personally interested why @Inee chose those tools.

Comment: because i use (and made) a tool called bintools (you can find it here https://github.com/lnee94/resh/blob/main/l/bintools ) and it has thos commands in it and it seems the most deterministic