# How can I use bash to replace a string in a file from another file

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

How can I use bash to replace a string in a file from another file
For example:

There is a path: `\\Hostname\example\example.txt`
I want to replace the `Hostname` with 162 hostnames from another file that contains the 162 hostnames then I save the result.
So the total path should be : 162 paths with different hostnames (162)

The first folder is : Paths.txt ( has 2 paths):

```
\\Hostname\example1\example1.txt
\\Hostname\example2\example2.txt
```

The Second file is: Hostname.txt ( has 162 hostnames )

I tried :

```
sed -i 's/Hostname/Hostname.txt/gI' Paths.txt
```

But the result is :

```
\\Hostname.txt\example1\example1.txt
\\Hostname.txt\example2\example2.txt
```

It did not read the real hostname inside the file Hostname.txt

Comment: Search and research for the use of `sed`.

Comment: Hello. Post the script YOU have written and someone may see any errors that might exist.

Comment: You are right David , I added the script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a straight answer to the question, but to solve this task you can use the following loop:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r hostname; do \
    printf '\\\\%s\\example1\\example1.txt\n' "$hostname" >> ./hosts-new.txt; \
    printf '\\\\%s\\example2\\example2.txt\n' "$hostname" >> ./hosts-new.txt; \
done < ./hosts-list.txt
```

Copy the above lines and run them as a single command (inline script).

Here are some explanations:

- `hosts-new.txt` is the output file.
- `hosts-list.txt` is the input file containing hostnames, each at new line.
- `IFS= read -r hostname` (at each loop's iteration) will read a line of the input file and assign it as a value of the variable that we named `$hostname`... as @StéphaneChazelas says in his [encyclopedic answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/201297) this is *the canonical way to read one line of input with the `read` builtin*.

  - The key is that *`read` reads words from a (possibly backslash-continued) line, where words are `$IFS` delimited and backslash can be used to escape the delimiters (or continue lines).* So the `read` command should be tweaked to read lines.
  - `IFS=` changes the *internal field separator* to the [null string](https://askubuntu.com/a/978715/566421), thus we preserve leading and trailing whitespace in the result.
  - The option `-r` - **r**aw input - disables interpretation of backslash escapes and line-continuation in the read data ([*reference*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read)).
- `printf '\\\\%s\\example\\example.txt\n' "$hostname"` will generate the desired output for each line. By `\\` we are escaping the special meaning of the single `\`. The character `\n` at the end means new line. `%s` is a string formatted placeholder of the value of the first positional parameter (of `printf`) which is our variable `$hostname`.
- The output redirection `>>` will append each line to the output file.
- By the part `< ./hosts-list.txt` at the end we are passing the content of the input file as input of the `while` loop, which is defined by the three keywords `while (condition); do (something); done`. So `while` reads the file line by line and, in this case, the *condition* is *while there is an input*.

---

Here is another version of the above, that probably will be faster because it will write to the new file only once after the loop is finished.

```bsh
while IFS= read -r hostname; do \
    printf '\\\\%s\\example1\\example1.txt\n' "$hostname"; \
    printf '\\\\%s\\example2\\example2.txt\n' "$hostname"; \
done < ./hosts-list.txt > ./hosts-new.txt
```

Note here is used the redirection `>` (instead of `>>`) that will override the content of the output file.

Comment: Many thanks pa4080 for your great efforts, what if I have more than one path in a file name: paths.txt?

Comment: Hi, @AbdalazizAlharthi, I just updated the answer. Probably there is a way to solve this task by `awk` script or some other much productive tool than bash loop but, I think this is the simplest solution...

Comment: Lovely and thanks again

Comment: @AbdalazizAlharthi, I've fixed a typo near to `do` admitted within the last edit. You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to read both the input paths and replacements from files, you could do something like this in GNU awk:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
  }
  NR==FNR {
    paths[FNR] = $0
    next
  }
  {
    for(i in paths)
      print gensub(/\\\\Hostname/,"\\\\"$0,"1",paths[i])
  }
' Paths.txt Hostname.txt
```

You can omit the `BEGIN` block if you don't care about the order of the paths for each host. You can probably safely omit the `\\\\` and `\\\\` in the `gensub` pattern and replacement (they're just included to anchor the `Hostname` string, in case it may may occur without the `\\` prefix elsewhere in the file).

You could also consider slurping the whole content of the `Paths.txt` file into a single multi-line string, and applying `gensub` with the `g` global flag instead of the loop:

```
gawk '
  NR==FNR {
    paths = paths (paths ? RS : "") $0
    next
  } 
  {
    print gensub(/\\\\Hostname/,"\\\\"$0,"g",paths)
  }
' Paths.txt Hostname.txt
```

or slurping the paths file as a single null-delimited record in a `BEGIN` block

```
gawk -v pathsfile="Paths.txt" '
  BEGIN {
    RS = "\0"
    getline paths < pathsfile
    RS = "\n"
  }
  {
    printf "%s", gensub(/\\\\Hostname/,"\\\\"$0,"g",paths)
  }
' Hostname.txt
```

or (should work in any awk)

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {
    paths = paths (paths ? RS : "") $0
    next
  } 
  {
    newpaths = paths
    gsub(/\\\\Hostname/,"\\\\"$0,newpaths)
    print newpaths
  }
' Paths.txt Hostname.txt
```

Comment: great answer. It handles multiple paths and hostnames easitly.