# How to startup application only on schedule?

Tags: startup

I would like to start on boot Slack only when I'm at work (basically, its 10:00 am till 18:00 pm on working days). I do not really want to write custom scripts, I would like to check this in more good way, for example:

[image: here]

But how? My first approach is to use cron's @reboot with date - not looks like its possible. Secondly, I've tried to search for tool, which you pass test string in crontab format and getting error code 1 or 0 back - no luck here.

Could you please point me in right direction?

Answer (score 4):

The command `date +%u` will output the day of the week as number. The command `date +%k` will output the current hour in 24h format. We can use command substitution `$()` and bash double brackets test `[[` to create an appropriate condition:

```
bash -c '[[ $(date +%u) == [1-5] && $(date +%k) == 1[0-7] ]] && /path/executable'
```

- `[1-5]` - is a regular expression that describes the working days of the week.
- `1[0-7]` - is a regexp that describes the working hours, it will cover from 10:00 to 17:59.
- `/path/executable` is a synopsis for the command/application that you want to run.
- Within the expression `[[ <condition-1> && <condition-2> ]]`, the logical and `&&` means that both conditions must be fulfilled.

According to the question, you can use the above command within `crontab`, or with Startup Applications. For couple of [reasons](https://askubuntu.com/a/978413/566421) I would prefer to use [Startup Applications](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/566421).

Comment: i think it will work, ill find out tomorrow.

Comment: @ТимурВалиев, it works in the command line. If there is an issue try to add `sleep 15 &&` in front of the command - 15 seconds should be enough for the graphical environment to be completely loaded.

Comment: Its not working for me. Tried few days, no luck. It works in commandline, but not via "Startup Applications"

Comment: how to set regex for different working hour? for example 9:00 - 18:00

Comment: @SurajShrestha, try with `$(date +%k) =~ ^9|1[0-7]$`. Here is a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21112809/6543935