# Using dbus-send in Cron

Tags: bash, gnome, scripts, cron, dbus

I want to setup a cron job to lock my session every day at three PM. When I enter `dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock`  in a terminal window, the session locks immediately,  but when I do the same in crontab (even by using a BASH script) it didn't work.
I want to create a BASH script to lock the session using `dbus-send` and add it to `crontab`.

Comment: I think the problem is In the terminal you are locking your screen. In Cron or systemd you are locking root's screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show notify-send messages triggered by crontab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978382/how-can-i-show-notify-send-messages-triggered-by-crontab) More explanations are available at https://github.com/pa4080/cron-gui-launcher

Answer (score 0):

Using loginctl to lock your desktop screen from crontab.

/opt/bin/lock-session.sh:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# crontab -e
# min hour dom month dow command
# 0 15 * * * /bin/bash -c /opt/bin/lock-session.sh

# Display     (is the first value of Sessions).
# Sessions    (array of sessions).
property=Sessions

for session in $(loginctl show-user $USER -p $property --value); do
    [[ \
    $(loginctl show-session $session -p Desktop --value) ]] && loginctl lock-session $session
done

exit 0
```