# Ubuntu - run bash script on startup with visible terminal

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, cron, startup

I am wanting to run a bash script on startup in Ubuntu 20.04 with the **terminal visible**. The test.sh file is located at /usr/bin/test.sh. I can get the test.sh file to run at startup but not in a visible terminal window.

Contents of test.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "hello";
```

I can not get it to work, I have tried (individually):

**Crontab (with and without the '&' and with/without "sudo")**

```
@reboot bash test.sh &

@reboot /usr/bin/test.sh &

@reboot DISPLAY=:0 xterm -hold -e bash -c "bash test.sh" &

@reboot DISPLAY=:0 xterm -hold -e bash -c "bash /usr/bin/test.sh" &
```

**Startup Applications Command**

```
sudo bash /usr/bin/test.sh
bash /usr/bin/test.sh
/usr/bin/test.sh
```

**Creating a Service at /etc/systemd/system/testService.service**

```
[Unit]
Description = Test Service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory= /usr/bin
ExecStart= /usr/bin/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And start, enable and checked status..

```
systemctl start testService.service
systemctl enable testService.service
systemctl status testService.service
```

But failed to start.

Any help / pointing in a better direction would be appreciated!

Comment: By terminal visible, did you mean the terminal will open and execute your script inside it. for your example would be `echo`-ing `hello` ?

Comment: konsole -e runs comands

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show notify-send messages triggered by crontab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978382/how-can-i-show-notify-send-messages-triggered-by-crontab)

Comment: @Liso yes, I want the .sh script to run in a visible GUI terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

To get a GUI terminal window to appear when you run your script:

Add to "Startup Applications" (under command):

```
bash test.sh
```

Contents of test.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
    DISPLAY=:0.0 xterm -hold -e bash helloWorld.sh
```

Contents of helloWorld.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "hello";
```

For me, this opened an XTerm terminal window upon login and ran the helloWorld.sh script.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.  Create a new script as below (call it say on_load.sh) who's job is to load your actual script. You can make that script run upon booting by putting an entry in your ~/.config/autostart

I am not sure if Ubuntu has autostart in the settings. I did mine in KDE Plasma and there its automated.

```
#! /bin/bash
konsole --noclose --workdir ~/usr/bin/ -e 'bash -c "~/usr/bin/test.sh; exec bash"' &
```

If you can't figure out how to put the above script in ~/.config/autostart, here is how it looks on my file.  KDE Plasma created a new file inside my ~/.config/autostart called on_load.sh.desktop

That file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/home/my_username/Documents/scripts/on_load.sh
Icon=dialog-scripts
Name=on_load.sh
Path=
Type=Application
X-KDE-AutostartScript=true
```

You need to ensure you have permissions to run both scripts.