# Unable to lock screen with Cron or Settings

Tags: 20.04, gnome, cron, lock-screen

Has anyone been able to use `crontab` to lock their screen automatically? I have tried all the suggested methods here but none seems to work. I have an **Ubuntu 20.04** gnome desktop and even the **Screen Lock** in the settings does not work. Only the following command works via the terminal:

> gnome-screensaver-command -l

Here is the current code block accessed by `sudo crontab -e`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

0 */1 * * * systemctl restart network-manager

0 */1 * * * systemctl restart teamviewerd

*/2 * * * * gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show notify-send messages triggered by crontab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978382/how-can-i-show-notify-send-messages-triggered-by-crontab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more universal way of [locking the screen](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Session_lock) is using:

```
loginctl lock-session
```

### Cron doesn't know the Session ID for `loginctl`

When you use `loginctl lock-session` from the command line, your session ID is already known. For example:

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_ID

c2

$ loginctl list-sessions

   SESSION        UID USER             SEAT            
        c2       1000 rick             seat0           

1 sessions listed.
```

The above shows two ways you can get your Session ID from the command line.

This GitHub issue for `loginctl` explains why the variable `XDG_SESSION_ID` is unknown to `systemd`. The same case would apply to `cron`:

- ["loginctl lock-session" fails when no explicit session passed #6032](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6032)

So from `cron` you could use `loginctl lock-session c2` if you knew your session ID would always be `c2`. An easier way is to use `lock-sessions`.

I tried this on my system and it works. Try using this on your `crontab -e`:

```
*/5  *   *  *   *     loginctl lock-sessions
```

Now, every five minutes your screen will lock.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. This command also works from the terminal but not with `crontab`.

Comment: @simguy I've revised the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but this also has the same issue. I have also added some more details to my question.

Here is how I implemented it for testing: "*/2 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /bin/loginctl lock-session"

Comment: @simguy Check for errors using `journalctl -xe`. One could show up every two minutes.

Comment: @simguy I've revised the answer after checking error messages and researching. If it works for you, remember to check the grey check mark next to the answer to show it solves the problem.

Comment: yes, it does! Thank you very much; I will mark it as the solution.