# How to give display access to a non-interactive shell using .bashrc

Tags: bashrc

I have a worker that is running in a non-interactive shell. The worker is needing to open up a chrome browser to do scraping, but we are getting a `chrome not reachable` error due to the worker not having access to the display. (same scripts work when using interactive shell)

How would I give this non-interactive shell worker access to the display in the .bashrc file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show notify-send messages triggered by crontab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978382/how-can-i-show-notify-send-messages-triggered-by-crontab)

Comment: @pa4080 Just gave it a shot, but no luck.

Comment: "non-interactive" has nothing to do with X access.  DISPLAY is an environment variable, so gets inherited from everything you spawn. If this "worker" is from somewhere else, did you set the xhost permissions to allow access?

Comment: Why would you do this using chrome? Can't you use a text-based browser? This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). It might make more sense to ask a question where you explain what you are trying to do, what the final objective is, because the idea of using something as resource-hungry and complex as chrome in a shell script really seems strange. And interactive vs non-interactive shouldn't make any difference. Are you sure both shells are bash? Isn't one actually `sh`? Does running `xhost +` help?

Comment: @ubfan1 @terdon  Sorry I'm quite new with ubuntu. I'm a php developer. We have a Laravel project hosted on an ubuntu server. There are daemon workers that are running jobs that are scrapping websites using a headful chrome browser (headless selenium has issues, so needs to be headful which is why we are using an ubuntu vm as our server). I can run the same job/scraper from my interactive terminal, but if I run it as a worker, which uses a non interactive shell, chrome does not start. I had to run `xhost +local:` to get the interactive terminal to work.